# UITableView Cell with CheckMarks

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I have got an iphone project that has a `UITableView` which is populated from Core Data..

When a cell is selected, the user is directed to a new view controller (see code line below) which shows additional information about that cell entry (from core data)

```
[self presentModalViewController:noteViewController animated:YES]
```

What i want to do is to be able to set some sort of checkmark on either side of each cell to represent whether the task is complete of incomplete..

I have read that i could do this using:

```
UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark
```

but i am not sure how to implement is as currently

```
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
```

is being used to present the modal view controller..

So essentially i want to know if there is a method for changing the state of a cell's accessory from checkmark to nothing (and vice versa) independently.. in the sense that if the actual checkmark is touch.. it shows it.. and if it is touched again, it hides it..

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 9):

You will need to track selected rows externally from Cell presentation. This means, your model (that you used to build the cells in the first place) will need to track some sort of boolean. Once you have that you set `accessoryType` to the proper type.

i.e.

```
if ([[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isSelected]) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
} else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

This would be some of the logic in your:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. i think i was a bit confusing in my question.. form what i have understood if a cell is selected will display/remove the checkmark.. but i want the checkmark to be independent in the sense that only change if the checkmark is selected.. is there any way to do this? i shall edit my original post

Comment: Would this not mean that any time a cell is selected, the accessory would change to? i want dont want it change everytime.. only to change it when the actual checkmark is selected.. is this possible??

Comment: can you PL tell me what is the "data" in your if condition and how to implement this... thanks

Answer (score 6):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

  if (selectedCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
  {
    selectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
  }
  else 
  if (selectedCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
  {
   selectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
  }
   //Do something
  }
```

Hope this helps

**UPDATE**

This [tutorial](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/30/iphone-sdk-tutorial-part-6-creating-custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder-uitableview/) will give you a basic info on custom table view cell.
Another [Reference](http://iphone.zcentric.com/2008/08/05/custom-uitableviewcell/).

I think [this](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/impliment-a-custom-accessory-view-for-your-uitableview-in-iphone/) will give you the solution.

Comment: Reading state back out of the GUI isn't a great idea: it goes against principles of MVC (Model-View-Controller) architecture.

Comment: Please check the original question.. i have updated with more specific information... Thank You for your answer though

Comment: I think you are talking about a custom button in the cell

Comment: Thank you.. that seems to be what i want.. could you by any chance direct me to something that would help me implement this?